# Displaying specific json data from URL

Tags: jquery, json, dogecoin-api

I'm trying to display the data for "total_txs" from this URL https://www.chain.so/api/v2/address/DOGE/DK1i69bM3M3GutjmHBTf7HLjT5o3naWBEk

I've put together the following but the div is blank. (Forgive me if its painfully simple to see what I'm doing wrong)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.getJSON("https://www.chain.so/api/v2/address/DOGE/DK1i69bM3M3GutjmHBTf7HLjT5o3naWBEk", function(data) {

$('#totaldonations').text(data.total_txs);
});
</script>

<div id="totaldonations"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` further contains a key named `data`, under which your desired attribute lies. So you need to extract the value as `data.data.total_txs`.

See the working demo below:

```js
$.getJSON("https://www.chain.so/api/v2/address/DOGE/DK1i69bM3M3GutjmHBTf7HLjT5o3naWBEk", function(data) {
  $('#totaldonations').text(data.data.total_txs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="totaldonations"></div>
```

To avoid any confusion, rename the callback argument to `response`, so the key becomes `response.data.total_txs`, which makes much more sense.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you, I've been pulling my hair out!

Comment: @Lelio Faieta Have done, there was a 10 time limit before I could accept it.
Cheers!